# Jquery move to top and bottom

Tags: jquery, image

I want to add jquery Scroll Up and Scroll Down images to my page. But I dont know how to do that. Its a single page website which can be seen at

The screenshot of the thing I want is at

http://i39.tinypic.com/2qajqy1.jpg

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add buttons to your webpage and set their position as fixed to prevent them moving up and down the page, you can then control the scroll position of hte page using JQuery's ScrollTop().

http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/